# How to convert display view of Date column from Psql database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql

I have a psql database set up with a date column that is the DATE type. When I receive the data from the database and try to display it in a table on my website the date appears with the timezone beside it.

Is there anyway to alter this so just the date shows when I'm displaying the data?

I set up my date column like so:

```
ALTER TABLE punches ADD COLUMN date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
```

when I display the date is shows like:

```
2019-04-02T04:00:00.000Z
```

I am hoping to get the output everything before the 'T04:00:00.000Z"

Comment: try `date.substring(0, 10)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: If you want to format the date using Javascript object you can visit the link https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercise-3.php . 

Another alternative is to use moment.js as it provides multiple functions to format a date.

Comment: @Viet Your solution is not really pertinent IMHO: following the timezone the date might be different. For example `2019-04-02T00:00:00.000` corresponds to the 1st of april (at 10 p.m.) in central Europe.

Comment: I understand that. It depends a lot on what @nick wants to do. That's why I posted as a comment (suggestion) not an answer based on what he wrote: `get the output everything before`. `moment.js` is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use To_Char() function.

Select To_Char(yourcolumn,'YYYY-MM-DD') From yourtable